# Image not uploading via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, image

I'm trying to upload an image by submitting form. Following is my code snippet:

**html:**

```
<form method="POST" id="statusform" action="insertstatus.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<textarea name="statusText" onclick="javascript:this.value='';" class="retroText" style="width:600px;height:100px;font-family:lucida sans unicode,lucida grande,sans-serif;resize:none;padding:5px;">Post your crap here ...</textarea>
<input type="file" name="statusPhoto" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/x-ms-bmp, image/x-png" size="26" />
</form>
```

**jquery:**

```
$("#statusform").submit(function() {

        $.post($("#statusform").attr("action"), $("#statusform").serialize(), function(data){           
            alert(data);
        });


        //Important. Stop the normal POST
        return false;
    });
```

**php:**

```
if(isset($_FILES['statusPhoto']) && $_FILES['statusPhoto']['size'] > 0)
{
         <Image Upload Code>
}
else
echo "Photo not submitted";
```

The message returned from ajax is: Photo not submitted.
Please help..!!

Comment: You'll have to use a FormData object to upload a file with ajax

Answer (score 1):

You are uploading, not the image, you uploading it name.

`$("#statusform").serialize()` return a string, image is a blob. Try to use some [jQuery plugins](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/), for example.

Comment: I'm just testing that whether $_FILES['statusPhoto'] is set or not.. But the thing fails here itself..

Comment: Ok. I understand that. But, if I don't want to use the plugin, what could be the possible solution. ?

Comment: `$_FILES` will be always empty by your `$.post`, because you don't send the file content, you send it name only. Try to submit you form to iframe if you don't want to reload page.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload file asynchronously by iframe as described in article:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/ajax-style-file-uploading-using-hidden-iframe/